# Removing item and value in Listview

Tags: c#, listview

I have a problem with removing items from my listview. This program calculates the total value of the remaining values in the list. The problem is that when I remove an item it removes the value of the first item added in the listview.

For example:

```
/*I added this items in order.

item1 = 20,
item2 = 10,
item3 = 5

When I remove item2 its rtbTcost is 15 based on the program below.
Which means that the value of item1 was removed.*/

                int totalRemoved = 0;


                for (int i = 0; i < lvCart.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    totalRemoved += int.Parse(lvCart.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text);
                    lvCart.Items.Remove(lvCart.SelectedItems[i]);

                }

                _listTotal -= totalRemoved;
                rtbTcost.Text = _listTotal.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

you    must     use     removeat 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983548(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

1Start at the end and count down.

```
for (int i = lvCart.SelectedItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
        ListViewItem itm = lvCart.SelectedItems[i];
        lvCart.Items[i].Remove();
}
```

Total Removed is

```
lvCart.SelectedItems.Count
```

if you are using the selected items from the list view,as the items to delete.

Sum after the delete, by summing the values in the column.

```
int _listTotal = 0;
foreach (ListViewItem li in lvCart) {
   _listTotal += int.Parse(li.Subitems[1].Text);
}
rtbTcost.Text = _listTotal.ToString();
```